# Remover caracteres duplicados em string se não for dígrafo

Tags: node.js, regex

Como remover caracteres duplicados em uma string, caso não seja  um dígrafo (rr, ss) usando Regex? Ex:

> Oiiiii => Oi
>
> Aloooo => Alo
>
> Passado => Passado
>
> Carroooo => Carro

Se o `rr` ou `ss` aparecer no começo ou no final da palavra, pode ser removido, ex:

> Carrosss => Carros

Comment: Existe a possibilidade de `r` ou `s` aparecer mais do que 2 vezes ? Se sim qual o procedimento nesse caso

Comment: Se isso acontecer, pode ser considerado só 2, e o resto removido. Ex: `carrrro = carro`

Comment: @ThiagoR. O que você ja tentou?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Começo por dizer que esta regex não cobre 100% dos seus casos, mas acerta em quase todos. E sinceramente não vejo muita forma de cobrir sem complicar drasticamente e talvez utilizar código à mão mesmo.

Mas começemos pela regex em si:

```
([^rs])(?=\1+)|(rr)(?=r+)|(ss)(?=s+)
```

[Veja no regex101](https://regex101.com/r/ZxRHYL/2/)

Explicação:

```
([^rs])  - Qualquer letra que não r ou s
(?=\1+)  - Que se repita uma vez ou mais
|(rr)    - Ou dois r's
(?=r+)   - Que tenham mais r's à frente
|(ss)    - Ou dois s's
(?=s+)   - Que tenham mais s's à frente
```

E faz a substituição por nada, texto vazio, pois o que é capturado são as letras duplicadas que você quer remover.

Teste:
Entrada:

```
oiiiiiiii amiggggos passssado Carrrrrrrros
```

Saida:

```
oi amigos passado Carros
```

Pode sempre ajustar a regex a outras letras que quer deixar duplicar, mexendo em `[^rs]` e nos grupos `(rr)`, adicionando outros que pretenda.

Repare que se você meter `Carross` a regex não consegue perceber que era suposto ser `Carros`, mais isso pode complicar e bem.

Comment: Muito bom! Já é o suficiente para mim. Muito obrigado pela ajuda!